# Login page that resolves direct url copy paste issue

Tags: asp.net

I have to make Login page in asp.net.

But this is not happening when I copy and paste the direct URL in browser.
How can i achieve that?

Example: If I have project.aspx and login.aspx and Project.aspx should not get accessed without Login.aspx even if URL is pasted in browser.

Comment: Can you give some more information? Like settings, code snippets etc.

Comment: Now I have Login.aspx which on successful login redirects to Project.aspx. But if I Write "www.mysite.com/project.aspx" then also I am able to access project.aspx page which I have to avoid. So how can I achieve that?

Comment: I am using sql database to store the username and pwds.

Comment: Use the source Luke !"GOOGLE IT!!!"  [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once successful login you can set a session variable.And in the each page loading you can check whether the session is null,if null you can redirect to login page.So that if user directly enter the URL, session will be null and it will redirect to login page

Comment: I am new to ASP.net. How can I do that? set a session variable.And check it at each page loading..

Comment: For login button click you can add  Session["Login"] = "Login"; And each page load you can check this.               if(Session["Login"] == null)
{Response.Redirect("/login.aspx");}                              and logout button you clear this session using Session.Abandon();

Answer (score 0):

If you are using standard asp.net authentication (eg Forms) you can specify in the web.config which paths or pages need to be authorized, If you use the standard login components, the url redirection to login and back to the pasted url will work automatically.

I would suggest using the standard asp.net mechanisms, and even better look at creating a custom membership provider.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer == null))
{
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}
```